# UI5 SimpleForm - how to display array values in the ColumnLayout

Tags: sapui5

UI5 newbie here. I've been using SimpleForm with the ColumnLayout for a while to display label+text to display my data. However, now one of the attributes in my model is not a simple text value, **but an array of values**. So, if I display them as text, all values are shown in a single row, separated by a comma. I would like to show them separately, each on its own line.

I tried to bind them to the `sap.m.List` or `sap.m.Table`, but no matter which control I try, I always get an error

```
sap.m.List (or Table) is not a valid Form content! 
Only use valid content in Element sap.ui.layout.form.ColumnLayout.
```

My question is - how can I display some sort of a list of tables (basically, an array) in the SimpleForm, which controls are allowed? I wasn't able to find it anywhere in the documentation and whether some different layout has to be used. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an Issue on how your data is formatted.

From what i can get your Array looks something like this.
["Value1,Value2","Value1","Value"]
To use a List Properly you would need the Data in a format like

```
[{propertyName1:"Value1",propertyName2:"Value1"},{{propertyName1:"Value1",propertyName2:"Value1"}]
```

Not a list here since i havent bothered to look the syntax up but the concept should be similar

```
                <Select
                width="100%"
                selectedKey="{
                    path: 'propertyName1'
                }"
                items="{/listBindingName()
                   }"
            >
                <core:Item
                    key="{propertyName1}"
                    text="{propertyName2}"
                />
            </Select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Allowed controls implement the interface sap.ui.core.IFormContent. You can see the list in the official API documentation [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.IFormContent) and clicking on "View Implementations".
There are a lot of controls in the list but (I fear) nothing that fits your needs, unfortunately.